# Find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

The function $f(x)$ is defined as following 
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
\cos x+e^x, & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
\ \alpha(1+x)^{2009}+\beta e^{-x}, & \text{if $x \ge 0$}
\end{cases} $$
I need to evaluate $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so that the function is **continuously differentiable**.

---

These are my thoughts:

Continuously differentiable $\Longleftrightarrow f^\prime(x) \ \text{exists and is continuous itself.}$ Thus we find the derivative of $f(x)$:
$$
f^\prime(x) = \begin{cases}
-\sin x+e^x, & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
\ 2009\alpha(1+x)^{2008}-\beta e^{-x}, & \text{if $x \ge 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
$\ f^\prime(x)$ definitely exists and is continuous, as:

- $-\sin x+e^x \ $ is continuous as a sum of two continuous functions
- $2009\alpha(1+x)^{2008}-\beta e^{-x} \ $ is continuous for the same reason
- now we need to pay special attention to $x=0$. $\ f^\prime(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ $\Longleftrightarrow \lim_{x \to 0^-}-\sin x+e^x=2009\alpha(1+0)^{2008}-\beta e^{-0} \\$

From which we get $$2009\alpha - \beta = 1$$

However we got an expression for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we still miss one equation in order to be able to determine both values. I am puzzled by the fact I don't know, where I can get the second expression from. What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable in $0$, then $f$ has to be continuous there as well!

Comment: @Stefan That's what I was thinking about, but got confused by the definition in Wikipedia: A function $f$ is said to be continuously differentiable if the derivative $f^\prime(x)$ exists, and is itself a continuous function.

Comment: By the way, I think it should be $2009\alpha - \beta = 1$. The limit at $-\sin(x)$ is 0.

Comment: @JoeyBF sure, you are right

Comment: Your solution is perfectly correct, but applying the same process to the original function $f$ instead of it's derivative gives another set of equations. A function that has a continuous derivative must also be continuous itself, in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to add that $f$ has to be continuos in $0$ as well.

You seem confused because wikipedia writes that you just need to check that $f'$ is continuos, and rightly so; in fact the fact that $f'$ exists implies that $f$ is continuos.

You may wonder then why you need to add a second equation; setting $f'$ continuos should result in $f$ being continuos automatically.

Basically, the point is that the expression you get for the derivative is not valid always, is valid only if $f$ is continuos. So you need to impose continuity of $f$, then your formula for $f'$ makes sense, and then you impose continuity of $f'$

Comment: That's a nice point, thanks!

Comment: you're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need $$\alpha + \beta = 2$$
in order for the function to be continuous at $x= 0$, a requirement for it to be continuously differentiable. Solving the system of this equation along with the one you have come up with simultaneously for $(\alpha,\beta)$ will give you the proper constants. Note that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\cos(x) + e^x\right] = 2$$
and
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\alpha(1 + x)^{2009} + \beta e^{-x}\right] = \alpha + \beta \,\,.$$

Comment: I don't actually need to find $\lim_{x \to 0} \left[\alpha(1 + x)^{2009} + \beta e^{-x}\right] = \alpha + \beta$, but just to estimate $f(0)$, upon definition of a continuous function: $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a) \Longrightarrow f(x)  $ continuous.

Comment: Either way, you need $\alpha + \beta = 2$ as I have said.

Comment: @DmitryKazakov I meant you need to impose this condition...

Comment: yes, I got it fully, thanks man

Comment: No problem, sorry for confusion. @DmitryKazakov